# How to find the linear part of a curve

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

How to automatically extract the well fitted linear part of a curve which the R^2 is not ideal for the whole curve?

for example
 What I have:

> data.lm

```
    x y
1   1 1
2   2 8
3   3 3
4   4 4
5   5 5
6   6 6
7   7 7
8   8 5
9   9 2
10 10 7
```

> rg.lm<- lm(y~x, data.lm)
>   rg.lm

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     3.7333       0.1939
```

> summary(rg.lm)

```
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.4788 -1.1136  0.0061  1.2712  3.8788 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   3.7333     1.6111   2.317   0.0491 *
x             0.1939     0.2597   0.747   0.4765  

Residual standard error: 2.358 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.06519,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.05166 
F-statistic: 0.5579 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.4765
```

What I expect:

> data.lm.ex<- unknown.function (data.lm)
>   data.lm.ex

```
    x y
1   3 3
2   4 4
3   5 5
4   6 6
7   7 7
```

Another example comes from real data:

> data.lm

```
   time    OD
1     0 2.175
2    30 2.134
3    60 2.189
4    90 2.141
5   120 2.854
6   150 3.331
7   180 3.642
8   210 4.333
9   240 4.987
10  270 5.093
11  300 4.943
12  330 5.198
13  360 4.804
```

> summary(lm(data.lm))$r.squared

```
[1] 0.8981063
```

> summary(lm(data.lm[4:9,]))$r.squared

```
[1] 0.9886727
```

> 

As it is shown above, the interval between line 4 to 9 has an absolutely higher r^2 than the whole curve. And would you please let me know the automatical way to find the interval which highest r^2 is presented and with at least certain number of points (due to 2 points always present the r^2=1.0)?

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
a <- cbind(1:10, c(1,8,3:7,5,2,7))
tmp <- rle(diff(a[,2]))
ml <- max(tmp$lengths)
i1 <- which(ml==tmp$lengths)[1]

a[seq(i1,i1+ml),]
```

**Update**

```
a <- data.frame(x=c(0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360), 
                y=c(2.175, 2.134, 2.189, 2.141, 2.854, 3.331, 3.642, 4.333, 4.987, 5.093, 4.943, 5.198, 4.804))

b <- diff(a[,2])/diff(a[,1])
b.k <- kmeans(b,3)
b.max <- max(abs(b.k$centers))
b.v <- which(b.k$cluster == match(b.max, b.k$centers))

RES <- a[b.v,]
plot(a)
points(RES,pch=15)
abline(coef(lm(y~x,RES)), col="red")
```

[image]

**A refined version:**

```
library(zoo)
a <- data.frame(x=c(0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360), 
                y=c(2.175, 2.134, 2.189, 2.141, 2.854, 3.331, 3.642, 4.333, 4.987, 5.093, 4.943, 5.198, 4.804))
f <- function (d) {
  m <- lm(y~x, as.data.frame(d))
  return(coef(m)[2])
}
co <- rollapply(a, 3, f, by.column=F)
co.cl <- kmeans(co, 2)
b.points <- which(co.cl$cluster == match(max(co.cl$centers), co.cl$centers))+1
RES <- a[b.points,]
plot(a)
points(RES,pch=15,col="red")
abline(lm(y~x,RES),col="blue")
```

[[image: an improved version]]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Regretfully, this solution is only available for a totally linear fitted part. It seems not work on real data that the R^2 can't be 1.0.

Comment: A real example was added in the edited question. At your convenience, would you help me find out the answer?

Comment: When I look at this new data you provided I see three linear parts. Which one you are interested in?

Comment: Sorry it's my fault that the two plateau priods were not considered as linear parts. For me the purpose is to extract linear elevating parts of the curve in such a reacting pattern.

Comment: Thanks. The problem has been solved by your method involving k-means.

Comment: Not a good approach. Take for example the following data set a=data.table('x'=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,16,18,24,28,32,36,48),'y'=c(0,3.13,4.93,5.86,6.25,6.28,6.11,5.81,5.45,5.06,4.66,3.9,3.24,2.67,2.19,1.2,0.81,0.54,0.36,0.1)). It will select the wrong set of points.